# Dotted outline around div element in table

Tags: firefox, html, border, outline, dotted-line

I have a **table element**, containting a custom usercontrol (contained in a "td" tag), that is a RadGrid from telerik. When i click anywhere in the div/cell zone (not a link, not an image, but inside a cell of the grid, anything that has not a a:link) and **there is a dotted line around the border of that div/cell**.

I succeeded of removing the equivalent **"orange" line that Chrome produce** in that case with css style

```
*:focus { outline:none;}
```

In **IE, i don't have the dotted line**, but i still **gotta remove that line in Firefox**. I tried css style:

```
div 
{
  border-style:none; 
  outline-style:none;
}
```

or

```
outline:0;
```

but no result so far.
Any idea?

[image: DottedOutlineImage]

Comment: i would add an image of the case but everytime i try to and save edits, image is not present in post.

Comment: This appear to be happening on RadGrid that has the "add row" functionnality available. If the grid is in "view mode", that dotted line doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

write it in css

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```